# How to run !dumpheap -dead on the generation 2 across all the heaps?

Tags: windbg

I have 8 managed gc heaps reported by `!eeheap -gc`:

```
0:000> !eeheap -gc
Number of GC Heaps: 8
------------------------------
Heap 0 (00000000009a2c50)
generation 0 starts at 0x00000000d92e3aa0
generation 1 starts at 0x00000000d8cdb128
generation 2 starts at 0x000000007fff1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000007fff0000  000000007fff1000  00000000d93edab8  0x593fcab8(1497352888)
Large object heap starts at 0x000000047fff1000
 segment     begin allocated  size
000000047fff0000  000000047fff1000  0000000487fabf00  0x7fbaf00(133934848)
00000004e6400000  00000004e6401000  00000004ee3af2f8  0x7fae2f8(133882616)
000000050e400000  000000050e401000  00000005152f8578  0x6ef7578(116356472)
0000000572400000  0000000572401000  00000005756e8ad8  0x32e7ad8(53377752)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x73544d00 (1934904576) bytes.
------------------------------
Heap 1 (00000000009ad690)
generation 0 starts at 0x00000001609a9cc8
generation 1 starts at 0x000000016072f780
generation 2 starts at 0x00000000ffff1000
ephemeral segment allocation context: none
 segment     begin allocated  size
00000000ffff0000  00000000ffff1000  0000000161bf8f50  0x61c07f50(1640005456)
Large object heap starts at 0x0000000487ff1000
 segment     begin allocated  size
0000000487ff0000  0000000487ff1000  000000048ffea910  0x7ff9910(134191376)
0000000044b50000  0000000044b51000  000000004cb44978  0x7ff3978(134166904)
000000051e400000  000000051e401000  000000052575aae0  0x7359ae0(120953568)
000000057a400000  000000057a401000  000000057c2e8610  0x1ee7610(32405008)
Heap Size:               Size: 0x7ae362c8 (2061722312) bytes.
...
```

I would like to run the `!dumpheap -dead` command on the gen 2 and LOH only, however, I am a bit confused as to:

1. The command clearly says where the gen 2 starts, but it is unclear to me where does it end. For example, for Heap 0 I figure I give `-start 0x000000007fff1000`, but what goes into `-end` ? Is it the start of gen 1?
2. I have 8 heaps, so I guess I have to run the `!dumpheap -dead` 8 times for gen 2. For LOH, which seems to span multiple fragments, the number of times is even higher. Is there a way to automate the process of dumping all these dead objects across all the LOHs and gen 2s?

Comment: For 1.: yes, start of gen 1 is end of gen 2 because the heaps get compacted after a GC.

Comment: LOH is sometimes referred to as gen 3: `!dumpheap -gen 3`

Comment: !dumpheap does not have the `-gen` argument. Which version of WinDBG do you use?

Comment: Sorry, it seems that was in a version of PSSCOR, not in SOS.